# Apollo Client - refetchQueries calling 2 times

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

refetchQueries calling multiple times on every `Add API call` in Apollo Client

**Here is my code**:

```
const [Add, { loading: applyLoad }] = useMutation(APPLY, {
    onCompleted(data) {
      do xyz
    },
    onError(error) {
      message.error(error.message);
    },
    awaitRefetchQueries: true,
    refetchQueries: [
      {
        query: ACTIVITIES_Y,
        variables: {
          sortBy: 'date',
        },
      },
      {
        query: ACTIVITIES_X,
        variables: {
          sortBy: 'date',
        },
      },
    ],
  });
```

I am using `graphql 15.5.0`.

Please suggest me possible solution.